# Android - Load a Fragment's View before Swapping Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity which contains a navigation drawer which displays different fragments when a different navigation item is pressed. The problem is one of these fragments has a noticeable delay when it is loaded.

During my activity's `onCreate` method, I start a thread which I want to preload each fragment so it can be easily swapped when the user presses a navigation item.

My code looks something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected void OnCreate {
        // Get instance of Thread InitialiseNavFrags.
        InitialiseNavFrags fragmentInit = new InitialiseNavFrags();
        fragmentInit.start();
    }
    private void selectItem(position) {
        ...
        final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Wait until sportsFragment is loaded.
        while (sportsFragment == null) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Caught InterruptedException :" + e);
            }
        }
        // Switches fragments to FavouriteFragment
        ft.replace(R.id.content_fragment, sportsFragment, "Sports");
        // Noticeable delay here
        ft.commit();
    }
    ...
    class InitialiseNavFrags extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            favouriteFragment = new FavouriteFragment();
            sportsFragment = new SportFragment();
        }
    }
}

public class SportsFragment extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView (...) {
        // Task with noticeable delay
        return view;
    }
}
```

My problem is that `SportFragment`'s `onCreateView` doesn't get executed until the `MainActivity`'s `selectItem` is executed and the fragment is swapped which causes the noticeable delay when the user presses on a navigation item.

So, is it possible to initialise the Fragment's view so that there is no noticeable delay?

Comment: You should never use `Thread.sleep()` on the main UI thread. You shouldn't create those fragments on a background thread, instead try to improve the `onCreateView()` of the faulty onCreateView()(too many views?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to create fragments on a seperate thread; you should optimize `OnCreateView` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it out yet, but I guess it is possible to only inflate a container in onCreateView and then inflate other views in a background thread and add them to that container once they are done inflating.

I am facing the same problem at the moment.